# Ansible issue ERROR! the playbook: samplebook.yml could not be found

Tags: ubuntu, ansible, cygwin

I am getting below error even though the file exists in the path.

> ERROR! the playbook: samplebook.yml could not be found

I have used below command to run the playbook

```
ansible-playbook samplebook.yml
```

**Update 1:**

[image]

Actually below command is creating yml file as swp file

```
vi samplebook.yml
```

`ls` command returning only `hello.txt` file 
I'm not getting why .yml and .cfg fies not getting recognized.

`swp` files getting deleted once I close command window.

Am I creating `yml` files in wrong way?

kindly suggest how to create `yml` file or `ansible playbook` in windows 7 using `Cygwin`

Ansible is already installed.

[image]

Comment: Can your elaborate on what you mean with `ìn the path` ? As you typed it, the file must be present in the current directory.

Comment: are you sure it's `.yml` not `.yaml`? Share `ls` command result in your working directory for example.

Comment: *Am I creating yml files in wrong way?* it sounds suspiciously like you have run `vi samplebook.yml` and entered content, and failed to press `<esc>` followed by `:wq`

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with ansible nor ubuntu nor cygwin. Choose a text editor you already manage (any IDE you are already used to will do) or  [learn to use vi](http://www.washington.edu/computing/unix/vi.html) if this is really what you want (but be ready for long hours in front of your computer because the learning curve is steep).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually I'm new to vi editor.

Below 2 links helped me a lot

[Learn vi](http://www.washington.edu/computing/unix/vi.html)

[vi editor](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-vi-editor.htm)

@Zeitounator Thanks for your suggestion. The Link provided by you gave me basic insights on vi usage.